# null result for average number of days by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select a.clientid, a.CaseType, b.EnrollmentStartDate, a.EligibilityStartDate, datediff(day, a.EligibilityStartDate, b.EnrollmentStartDate) as date_diff         
INTO ##temptable1 
FROM dbo.Client a, dbo.ClientEnrollment b
WHERE a.ClientId = b.ClientId 
AND a.CaseType = 99
ORDER BY a.ClientId



select avg (date_diff) from ##temptable1
```

so the above query gives me the overall average number of days it takes for a client to enroll into a program from their eligibility start date. I now want to sort the results by each month

```
select avg (date_diff) from ##temptable1 
where EligibilityStartDate = '2019-03-01
```

for some reason I'm getting NULL no matter what date I specify ( even though the original query produces over 40k results ) I've tried inserting `EligibilityStartDate = '2019-03-01'` into the table itself but that did not work either.

Comment: Are you sure there actually are rows with non-null values for the search criteria `EligibilityStartDate = '2019-03-01'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The result I'm currently getting produces the overall average, but say I want to get the average for clients who became eligible in April. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(c.EligibilityStartDate) as yyyy,
       MONTH(c.EligibilityStartDate) as mm,
       AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, c.EligibilityStartDate, ce.EnrollmentStartDate) as date_diff         
FROM dbo.Client c JOIN
     dbo.ClientEnrollment ce
     ON c.ClientId = ce.ClientId AND c.CaseType = 99
GROUP BY YEAR(c.EligibilityStartDate), MONTH(c.EligibilityStartDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(c.EligibilityStartDate), MONTH(c.EligibilityStartDate);
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases (i.e. abbreviations of table names) rather than meaningless ones.
- You seem to want an aggregation query.